# Convert list of lists of 1 and 0 in black and white image in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, image

I would like to know if there is a simple way to convert a simple list of 0 and 1 for example:

```
[[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
 [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
 [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
 [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
 [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]]
```

Into a black and white image, for example for the previous list, this image :
[smiley](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztQ1u.jpg)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `matplolib` (I named as `X` your input matrix):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
im = plt.imshow(X, cmap='Greys')
plt.show()
```

[image]